# nginx: Prevent DoS by limiting worker processes/connections

Tags: nginx, denial-of-service

If I limit my nginx worker processes to 1 and allow for 500 connections, what happens if I exceed this limit? Does the server return a 503 Service Unavailable?

Basically, I'm trying to secure my system against DoS and do not expect more than 500 simultaneous connections per second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How many cores your server has ? If you have two cores, i suggest you can set 2 workers and 250 conn. max.

max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections

And Yes, the 501 connection will receive an error. But be carefull, a browser opens 2 connections by default.

EDIT: One more thing, you can set a max connection limit by IP (10 here) with

```
## Max conns for one ip
 limit_zone gulag $binary_remote_addr 5m;
 limit_conn gulag 10;
```

in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Thanks Adrien, very helpful. My server only has one core so I set it to 1. I will double the amount of connections then. Is a connection immediately closed after the user has been served the needed content?

Comment: Yes of course, a connection is immediately closed after the content has ben served but if the attacker use only a SYN and no ACK (SYN flood attack) with the default timeout of nignx (60s) you can set:
 client_body_timeout 15;
 client_header_timeout 15;
 keepalive_timeout 15;
 send_timeout 15;
In the http{} section.

Comment: This is a great configuration and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again Adrien.